# Is it possible to raise the validator for text box on drop down changed

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, validation

Hi all generally we can handle validators on Button click or when the control is left empty. I am having my requirement as follows

I am having a text box and a drop down where the drop down list is binded with database values as follows

```
  mlocal_strStoredProcName = USADAO.StoredProcNames.PayFrequency_uspPayFrequencySelect;
  oEmployee.Select(out mlocal_ds, mlocal_strStoredProcName);
  ddlPaymentType.DataSource = mlocal_ds;
  ddlPaymentType.DataTextField = TablesAndColumns.tblPayFrequency_PayFrequencyDesc;
  ddlPaymentType.DataValueField = TablesAndColumns.tblPayFrequency_PayFrequencyTypeID;
  ddlPaymentType.DataBind();
  ddlPaymentType.Items.Insert(0, "Select");
  mlocal_ds.Clear();
```

What i need is if the text box is left empty on ddlPaymentType_SelectedIndexChanged i would like to fire the validator is it possible to do if so can any one give me an idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer just used

```
  Page.validate("g")
```